# How to check if on multiple address checkout page?

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, multiple-checkout

I need a way to check if the customer is using multiple checkout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending from where to check it you can either use `Mage::app()->getRequest()` or *if available (like in controllers)* `$this->getRequest()` ...

```
$request = Mage::app()->getRequest();

if ($request->getModuleName() == 'checkout' && $request->getControllerName() != 'onepage')
# or
if ($request->getModuleName() == 'checkout' && $request->getControllerName() == 'multishipping')
```

Answer (score 3):

If  customer is using multiple checkout then the URL of the website would be different then the normal checkout..

**Multiple Checkout**

```
https://www.domain.com/checkout/multishipping/
```

**Normal Checkout**

```
https://www.domain.com/checkout/onepage/
```

You can identify it by URL. Thanks :)

Comment: That works but I was wondering if there is a Magento code for it?

Comment: where you want to put your check? In Checkout Page , Observer or Success page?